# My command only works when I run it from terminal. It does not work when I use a launcher. What should I do to fix that?

Tags: command-line, launcher, gnome-terminal

I use the following command to control my phone remotely with *scrcpy*:

```
adb kill-server ; adb connect (my phone's IP address):5555 ; scrcpy --prefer-text --serial (my phone's IP address)
```

It runs without a problem in terminal and the program starts so that I can use it. But when I use a desktop launcher to run the same command, the terminal opens and closes immediately and the program doesn't start (I have "Run in terminal" enabled in the launcher properties). What should I do to make it work?

Here is the output that I get when running the command in terminal:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
connected to (my phone's IP address):5555
INFO: scrcpy 1.12.1 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
/usr/share/scrcpy/scrcpy-server: 1 file pushed. 0.9 MB/s (24773 bytes in 0.026s)
error: more than one device/emulator
ERROR: "adb reverse" returned with value 1
WARN: 'adb reverse' failed, fallback to 'adb forward'
INFO: Initial texture: 720x1280
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The launcher is likely treating the entire string as a single command. In your case, everything following `adb` (`... ; ... ; ...`) are treated as arguments, not executed as separate commands. To work around the issue, use `bash -c`.

```
bash -c "adb kill-server ; adb connect 0.0.0.0:5555 ; scrcpy --prefer-text --serial 0.0.0.0"
```